# "Error: Timeout reached while waiting for PID 212" while decrypting LUKS over SSH

Tags: ssh, luks, initramfs, cryptsetup, dropbear

I've been trying to open a LUKS container via SSH using dropbear and initramfs/initrd image. My setup works well. I mean, I log via SSH to the target machine, then I see the prompt saying `Please unlock disk rpi_crypt:` , and then I enter the right password and the LUKS container is being opened and the system boots. But when I typed the password via SSH, after a few secs I got the following error:

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.239
Please unlock disk rpi_crypt:

Error: Timeout reached while waiting for PID 212.
Connection to 192.168.1.239 closed.
```

So where does this error come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue.  I was able to successfully SSH in after the initramfs ssh connection closed.

- The drive most likely did successfully decrypt and mount.
- Try to ssh in normally (using os credentials)

I do not know the root cause for the message.